# Zend2 form validation with jQuery form validation plugin

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2, jquery-validate

I am new in Zend 2.I created a registration form and am using jQuery form validation plugin to validate it. Now i want to check whether the email already exists or not(with zend 2 and jQuery form plugin). Can anyone help me implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('.register-form').validate({
                rules: {

```
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: baseUrl+'/login/emailcheck',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                          mail: function(){ return $("#email").val(); }
                        },
                    }
                },

            },

            messages: { // custom messages 

                email: {
                    required: "Email is required.",
                    remote: 'Email already Exists.'
                },

            },

        });
```

and in Logincontroller,

public function emailcheckAction(){

```
        $email =  $_POST['mail'];
        $result =  $this->getRegistrationInfoTable()->getEmail($email);
        if($result){
            $value = false; //'Email already exists';
        }else{
            $value = true;
        }
        $result = new JsonModel(array(
            'response' => $value
        ));

        return $result;
 }
```

and i edited the jquery.validate.js to respond to the json array also. 
Now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the jQUery.FormValidation, but i know how i would go on about this kind of Feature. And this is basically the same as in ZF1.

I would write a custom action, something like `partialValidationAction()` that is given a parameter `element`. Now to that action you'd `POST` your Form. Inside the action then, since it's given the parameter `element`, you'd set the `validationGroup` of your form to only this one element and then you'd validate the form.

The action then would simply return `true` if the element has validated and a JSON-Object containing the error-messages if it's validation returns false. So whenever you get a JSON-Object with error messages, add them to your form element and you're done.

I'd do it like this for several reasons and one is maintainability. IIRC that formValidation from jQuery requires the rules to be set within JS-Code, right? That would mean you'll have to maintain your Validation-Rules on two different places which usually is a bad thing and pretty much always leads to a mismatch in Rules.